# Failed to read candidate component class

Tags: spring, hibernate, gwt

I am writing a GWT project and I was able to run it. When I integrate Spring alone, it works but then I tried integrating Hibernate and this screwed up the things. I am getting the below error.

I tried, debugging through the source code of Spring, but unfortunately I do not see where it throws the exception from.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read    
candidate component class: file [C:\ws\TicTacToe\war\WEB-INF\classes\com\tic\server\dao\entity\UserEntity.class]; nested exception is 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 165: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 165
```

I am sure this won't make much sense.Here is the complete error trace:

```
WARNING: Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:    
Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\all-development-tools\all-
eclipse\eclipse-kepler\ws\TicTacToe\war\WEB-
INF\classes\com\tic\server\dao\entity\UserEntity.class]; nested exception is  
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 165:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 165
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readLabel(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:64)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:257)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:123)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:219)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:154)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:140)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:282)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:249)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:306)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:79)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:88)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:241)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
```

**EDIT:**

```
package com.tic.server.dao.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -329211977029380182L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name = "CITY")
private String city;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `UserEntity.java`?

Answer (score 6):

Another reason for this error is using Spring 3 on a project running with Java 8 lambdas. Spring 3 doesn't support lambdas, so you need to upgrade to Spring 4 or remove all lambdas from your code. This is a more common case for this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer for this question.. I would say a partial answer:

This is a GWT application which I want to upload on GAE, so I had all the GAE jars there, the moment I removed them and removed the appengine configuration, I was able to successfully run it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing,Now you should change the title to  relevant problem :)